# Percentage uncertainty (average) of measuring tool

Tags: experimental-physics, mass, measurements, error-analysis

I am using a measuring tool and it provided me with $10$ measurements:

$m_1 \pm u_1\%,m_2 \pm u_2\%,m_3\pm u_3\%, \ldots m_{10}\pm u_{10}\%.$ Note that these are not all measurements of the same thing.

Is it correct to say that the average percentage instrumental uncertainty is:

Average of individual percent uncertainties $= \frac{u_1 + u_2 + u_3 + \ldots + u_{10}}{10}?$

Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to SE. Could you please update your question and make it clearer what you mean by "these are not all measurements of the same thing". E.g. write explicitly what you measure. Otherwise any answer will only help you and not other users as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a scale measuring something like a mass to $1g$ you would have two measurements $1 \pm 1 \textrm{g}$ or $u=100\%$ and $100 \pm 1\textrm{g}$ or $u=1\%$. I doubt if you would give your scale a uncertainty of $50.5\%$.
So I think it is not a good idea to take the mean value of errors in %.

Answer (score 0):

as a metrologist, I wouldn't do that. Not because is not right, but because you could be undestimating your instrument's uncertainty. Usually what we metrologists do is take the greatest uncertainty, for the maximum entropy principle, because there's nothing more wrong than underestimating your unc